# Identify a hanging plant with spherical leaves

Tags: species-identification, botany

[image]

This plant was found in the "drylands" section of a public conservatory (you can see a potted cactus in the background).  It did not have a label, and there was nobody around to ask about it.  The plant has hanging stems about a meter long, with spherical leaves about five millimeters in diameter -- the leaves appear to be genuinely spherical, not curled-up flat leaves.

Any idea what it is?

Comment: you could have googeled "hanging plant with spherical leaves"

Comment: Top result was a Wikipedia article for a plant with spherical *fruit*, and the next several were plants with curled-up leaves.  Google doesn't have all the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that this might be *Curio rowleyanus*, sometimes called "string-of-pearls".  The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curio_rowleyanus) indicates it has spherical leaves about 6mm in diameter on trailing stems up to about a meter.  It is a succulent and the spherical leaves reduce evaporation for volume contained.  It grows in the dry parts of southwest Africa.

Comment: BTW, my Google query was simply _plant with spherical leaves_.

Comment: Looks correct to me. Incidentally, there are a bunch of similar "String of..." plants in the same or very closely related genus *Senecio*, and they are all very easy to propagate from the leaves and stem, so are incredibly popular houseplants at the moment.